# JQuery search filter not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

The search function is not correctly filtering the results properly. The first row always shows regardless of whether a match can be found, or not.

Your help is appreciated.

```js
$("#search").keyup(function () {
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();

    $("table tr").each(function (index) {
        if (!index) return;
        $(this).find("td").each(function () {
            var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
            var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1);
            $(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found);
            return not_found;
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        <table>
        <tr>

        <td class="col-nome">Ixpira</td>
        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Live</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td class="col-nome">SunHotels</td>
        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Live</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="col-nome">World 2 Meet [W2M]</td>
        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Live</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td class="col-nome">ImperatoreTravel.it</td>
        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Live</span></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="  live search"></input>
```

Comment: just remove `if (!index) return;` and it will works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you have this line in your code:

```
if (!index) return;
```

but it's causing the problem. jQuery `.each()` is 0-based, so the first item it iterates through will cause the function to return (0 is equal to false).

```js
$("#search").keyup(function () {
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();

    $("table tr").each(function (index) {
        $(this).find("td").each(function () {
            var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
            var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1);
            $(this).parents('tr').toggle(!not_found);
            return not_found;
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
        <tr>

        <td class="col-nome">Ixpira</td>
        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Live</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td class="col-nome">SunHotels</td>
        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Live</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="col-nome">World 2 Meet [W2M]</td>
        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Live</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td class="col-nome">ImperatoreTravel.it</td>
        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Live</span></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="  live search">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#search").keyup(function () {
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();

    $("table tr").each(function (index) {
        $(this).find("td").each(function () {
            var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
            var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1);
            $(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found);
            return not_found;
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        <table>
        <tr>

        <td class="col-nome">Ixpira</td>
        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Live</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td class="col-nome">SunHotels</td>
        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Live</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="col-nome">World 2 Meet [W2M]</td>
        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Live</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

        <td class="col-nome">ImperatoreTravel.it</td>
        <td><span class="badge badge-success">Live</span></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="  live search"></input>
```

Why `if (!index) return;` ? It will skiping the first element

```js
index_of_first_element = 0;

if(!index_of_first_element){
 console.log('First element skipped');
} else {
 console.log('First element not skipped');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your return for !index is returning when 0. I removed it and now it works:

```js
$("#search").keyup(function() {
  var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();

  $("table tr").each(function(index) {
    $(this).find("td").each(function() {
      var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
      var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1);
      $(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found);
      return not_found;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>

    <td class="col-nome">Ixpira</td>
    <td><span class="badge badge-success">Live</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="col-nome">SunHotels</td>
    <td><span class="badge badge-success">Live</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-nome">World 2 Meet [W2M]</td>
    <td><span class="badge badge-success">Live</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="col-nome">ImperatoreTravel.it</td>
    <td><span class="badge badge-success">Live</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="  live search"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

All your code is working fine, only the line `if (!index) return;` is causing the trouble, what it does is

`index` returns the numbers [0,1,2,3 ...] in `$.each()`, so when first row was reached the index was `0`, and `!0 = 1` thus the *if* condition was satisfied and returned back without eliminating the first row.

```js
$("#search").keyup(function () {
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();

    $("table tr").each(function (index) {
        
        $(this).find("td").each(function () {
            var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
            var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1);
            $(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found);
            return not_found;
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>

    <td class="col-nome">Ixpira</td>
    <td><span class="badge badge-success">Live</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="col-nome">SunHotels</td>
    <td><span class="badge badge-success">Live</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-nome">World 2 Meet [W2M]</td>
    <td><span class="badge badge-success">Live</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="col-nome">ImperatoreTravel.it</td>
    <td><span class="badge badge-success">Live</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="  live search"></input>
```